# How to resolve BackgroundContainer.dll error on startup?

Tags: windows, boot, malware

When I start my desktop it gives me an error about `BackgroundContainer.dll`.

[image]

How to get rid of it?

I found nothing when i started regedit.exe and searched (<kbd>F3</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) for BackgroundContainer.dll

Comment: Interesting. Have you considered searching for that error online to see if there are any solutions? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to search but found nothing

Comment: [This was the first result](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/protect/forum/protect_scanner-protect_scanning/run-dll-error-messagebackground-containerdll/49612202-667e-4a71-8e9a-d02161d8bc19) when I searched for "conduit backgroundcontainer.dll"

Answer (score 7):

This was a malware. It was removed by your AntiVirus Scanner, but the registry entries are still present to start the malware at startup.

Start `regedit.exe` and search (<kbd>F3</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) for `BackgroundContainer.dll` and delete all entries you find.

To be safe, make a full scan with an AntiVirus Scanner like Microsoft Security Essentials/ Defender and also scan your PC with Malwarebytes' Anti-Malware.

If you can find nothing in the registry, [download and run Autoruns from sysinterals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) and look here for an entry " BackgroundContainer". Look under `logon` and `scheduled task` first. When found, left click on the entry to highlight it. Then right click on your mouse and select delete from the menu that comes up for that entry. Right click on delete to delete that entry. Be careful to only delete the entry/entries you want to permanently delete.

Comment: MalwareByte's has a 5 step removal process that is outlined here. 
http://malwaretips.com/blogs/backgroundcontainer-dll-virus-removal/