# Startup error BackgroundContainer.dll on windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-8, boot, windows-8.1, dll

I have the same problem with this topic!
[How to resolve BackgroundContainer.dll error on startup?](https://superuser.com/questions/661971/how-to-resolve-backgroundcontainer-dll-error-on-startup/662447?noredirect=1#comment836344_662447)

The thing is i did everything that says in answer but

i)I found nothing when i started regedit.exe and searched (F3 or CTRL+F) for BackgroundContainer.dll

ii)I made a full scan with AntiVirus Scanner like Microsoft Security Essentials/ Defender and also i scaned my PC with Malwarebytes' Anti-Malware,but i found nothing.

So this pop up message on start up keep appeared!

any idea?

I know you will say that its a duplicate of this topic but when i did that question the deleted it and said if you have a question post it!Sorry about that.

Thank you!

Comment: Just becuase the existing answer(s) don't work for you doesn't mean you should post the same question again.  Please add comments or perhaps [earn some rep](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) and post [a bounty](http://superuser.com/help/bounty) on the existing question, pointing out what you tried and how it didn't work for you.

Comment: My friend i comment and they deleted my comment with the reason if you have a question post it!

here is their answer:

"Welcome to Super User! If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the Ask Question button. If you have sufficient reputation, you may upvote the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers"

Comment: The idea of a duplicate is that the same issue shouldn't be posted in two places unless it's a different problem. There's no need to have 4 posts all with the exact same issue.

Comment: @ManolisKaragiannis No problems. :)  With the other question, what you did was post your 'comment' as as 'answer', so it was removed. I can see how the generic comment provided on removal could be confusing though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the exploit was cleaned up, it left behind a scheduled task which loads when Windows starts. Naturally, the task can no longer find the program it was going to run.  See http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/protect/forum/protect_scanner-protect_scanning/run-dll-error-messagebackground-containerdll/49612202-667e-4a71-8e9a-d02161d8bc19